# How to merge headers with same name into one single header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm going to add MultiIndex column to my dataframe.
What I got:

[image]

What would I like to get:

[image]

full code:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

dictionary = {1: 'row1', 2: 'row2', 3: 'row2', 4: 'row2', 5: 'row3'}

dictionary1 = {1: 'row4', 2: 'row5', 3: 'row6', 4: 'row7', 5: 'row3'}
dictionary2 = {1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1}

data = data.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append(dictionary1, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append(dictionary2, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append(dictionary2, ignore_index=True)
data = data.append(dictionary2, ignore_index=True)
```

What I did:

```py
arrays = [['row1', 'row2', 'row2', 'row2', 'row3'],
          ['row4', 'row5', 'row6', 'row7', 'row3']]
data.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)

data
```

Comment: please provide your datasets as DataFrame constructors (this is important for reproducible examples with MultiIndexes)

Comment: your full code **as text**, obviously

Comment: I've added full code. I just set first 2 rows as MultiIndex column

Comment: images as useless to reproduce your examples: [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: arrays = [['row1', 'row2', 'row2', 'row2', 'row3'], ['row4', 'row5', 'row6', 'row7', 'row3']]

data.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)

data

Comment: Is that now ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, note that hiding a label is probably a bad idea if you're going to work with the data. The will prevent you from logically selecting your data.

That said, if you really want to do this, you could convert the MultiIndex to DataFrame and use `duplicated` to `mask` the duplicated labels:

```
idx = data.columns.to_frame()
data.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(idx.mask(idx.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,
                                                           axis=1)
                                                 ).fillna(''),
                                        names=[None]*data.columns.nlevels)
```

output:

```
   row1  row2              row3
   row4  row5  row6  row7      
0  row1  row2  row2  row2  row3
1  row4  row5  row6  row7  row3
2     5     4     3     2     1
3     5     4     3     2     1
4     5     4     3     2     1
```